Combining predefined list with custom entry in attribute form
Currently, I am working on a project to map plants outdoors. I would like to have a drop down menu to choose from a list of known species. But no list is complete and occasionally, I have to use incomplete names if I am in doubt.
I am searching for a solution with which I can choose a name in a list preferably with a search bar, but also, where I'll be able to use custom names not yet in the list, so that they get saved automatically.
Unique values is not suitable for a couple of thousand names, but you can add new names without problem. Value relation on the other hand gives you a list to work with and a search bar, but you can't use a name which isn't in the list, just by writing it out. You have to create a new entry in your list. That's annoying.
I hope, someone here knows a solution to that. I am planning to use ist with QField (idk if Plugins etc. work with it or not).
